# how can i order results by in condition with oracle

Tags: oracle

My codes like;

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FNO IN(1,8,3,7,11,2)
```

this query result like

```
    FNO 
1
2
3
7
8
11
```

How can i get result like my in condition.
Like;

```
FNO
1
8
3
7
11
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the values inside a collection and then generate a row number for the collection indexes and order by that:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                COLUMN_VALUE AS value
         FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 8, 3, 7, 11, 2))
       ) v
       ON (t.fno = v.value)
ORDER BY v.rn;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (fno, item) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'Item' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
```

Outputs:

> | FNO | ITEM |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Item1 |
> | 8 | Item8 |
> | 3 | Item3 |
> | 7 | Item7 |
> | 11 | Item11 |
> | 2 | Item2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3e695ae2157c03e40ee09cfa48cc4f69)*

Comment: thanks for all,
İ solved it with your suggestion

SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                COLUMN_VALUE AS value
         FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1, 8, 3, 7, 11, 2))

Comment: This is the most straightforward and low-code way

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of ORDER BY and CASE WHEN, as example:

```
SELECT fno
FROM table
WHERE fno IN (1,8,3,7,11,2)
ORDER BY CASE fno
WHEN 1 THEN 1
WHEN 8 THEN 2
WHEN 3 THEN 3
WHEN 7 THEN 4
WHEN 11 THEN 5
WHEN 2 THEN 6
END
```

See this example working here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c280fa234e87d3ea93083ad1cf94f5f5)

Comment: thanks for answer but i have too many conditions
it's so hard for me to do this

Comment: Then you should- depending on your setup - create a second table that provides the sorting information or apply the sorting using a procedure or even external program.

Answer (score 0):

You can order using `DECODE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE FNO IN (1, 8, 3, 7, 11, 2)
ORDER BY DECODE(FNO, 1, 1, 8, 2, 3, 3, 7, 4, 11, 5, 2, 6);
```

If you expect many values each of which would require a custom sorting level, then you should maintain a second table which stores this information:

```
Table: FNO_SORT

FNO | pos
1   | 1
2   | 6
3   | 3
7   | 4
8   | 2
11  | 5
```

Now we can join to this table and then order using the `pos` field:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM yourTable t
INNER JOIN FNO_SORT f ON f.FNO = t.FNO
WHERE t.FNO IN (1, 8, 3, 7, 11, 2)
ORDER BY f.pos;
```

Comment: (1, 8, 3, 7, 11, 2) its was example
i have too many condition more then 100

Comment: Check the updated answer for a join approach to workaround your problem.